# Add column representing the median for each group in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe `het` that has the following layout:

```
SampleID   expr  Gene        Period  Consequence            isPTV
HSB430    -1.23  ENSG000098  4       upstream_gene_variant  0
HSB321    -0.02  ENSG000098  5       stop_gained            1
HSB296     3.12  ENSG000027  4       upstream_gene_variant  0
HSB201     1.22  ENSG000027  4       intron_variant         0
HSB220     0.13  ENSG000013  6       intron_variant         0
```

I'm trying to organize it such that I group by the `Gene` and then get the median `expr` across all `SampleIDs` for that `Gene`. I've attempted to do this via the following:

```
het_grouped= het.groupby(['Gene'])['expr'].median().reset_index()
```

The **problem** I'm having with this is:

1) it's getting rid of my other columns (it only results with the `Gene` and `expr` columns).

2) the median value is replacing the original `expr` value. I'd like the `Median` to come up in a separate column.

I tried to address 2) by doing the following, but the resulting `Median` column comes up as blank:

```
het["Median"]= het.groupby(['Gene'])['expr'].median()
```

Here is my **expected output**:

```
SampleID   expr  Gene        Period  Consequence           isPTV  Median
HSB430    -1.23  ENSG000098  4       upstream_gene_variant  0    -0.625 
HSB321    -0.02  ENSG000098  5       stop_gained            1    -0.625
HSB296     3.12  ENSG000027  4       upstream_gene_variant  0     2.17
HSB201     1.22  ENSG000027  4       intron_variant         0     2.17
HSB220     0.13  ENSG000013  6       intron_variant         0     0.13
```

Comment: Just use het["Median"]= het.groupby(['Gene'])['expr'].transform('median')